# Firebase job dispatcher is not working at Oreo devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

i'm using a firebase job dispatcher api to run a service in background. In Marshmallow it is working fine, but while coming to Oreo devices it not working. it is showing error or warning messages like

> 2019-02-04 14:20:22.285 2525-5699/? E/NetworkScheduler: Dropping task
>   as app's play services SDK version does not support Android O. Either
>   update the SDK or lower your app's target SDK version. Package:
>   com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample

I already done what is mentioned in firebase job dispatcher api step in git hub.

**MainActiviy.java**

```
package com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample;    
import android.app.job.JobInfo;    
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;    
import android.content.ComponentName;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.util.Log;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.widget.Button;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Constraint;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Lifetime;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.RetryStrategy;    
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Trigger;       
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG="MAIN ACTIVITY";
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));

}

public void startjob(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startjob: ");
    Job job = createJob(dispatcher);
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);

}

public void stopjob(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "cancelJob: ");
    dispatcher.cancelAll();
}

public Job createJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createJob: ");
    Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            // persist the task across boots
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            // Call this service when the criteria are met.
            .setService(MakeService.class)
            // unique id of the task
            .setTag("LocationJob")
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            // We are mentioning that the job is not periodic.
            .setRecurring(true)
           // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            // .setTrigger(Trigger.NOW)
            //Run this job only when the network is avaiable.
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();
    return job;
}
}
```

**MakeService.java**

```
package com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;


import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MakeService extends JobService {
    boolean jobintentService=false;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler= new Handler();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters job) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob: ");
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Handler");
                handler.postDelayed(this,10000);
            }
        },10000);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters job) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob: ");
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission=""
            android:name=".MakeService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build (Project)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'

}
```

i expect that to work, i'm not knowing what is going on.

** SOlUTION **
it is due to the version
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
i updated it, it working from now

Comment: "it not working", can you be a bit more specific? do you get unexpected behavior? do you get error messages? ..

Comment: hi, Stultuske. i updated the question. if you need more, please ask me

Comment: have you read those error messages and followed their suggestion?

Comment: i tried to add play service to app dependence but it warns we to don't use it, it is already comes with firebase

Answer (score 0):

The error message literally  has the solution

> Either update the SDK or lower your app's target SDK version. Package:
>   com.webappclouds.jobserviceexample

Update your library from `0.5.2`

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

I've also noticed you have an empty permission value on your manifest, remove it.

```
android:permission=""
```

Let me know if this helps

---

I would recommend you to migrate to `WorkManager` since it is a more backward compatible and simpler API. When using this library *all* your API level restrictions are taken care of (restrictions is different from security).

You can find a simple workflow example here:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#java

And the documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

I recommend you read both.

- Android Oreo Background Execution Limits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc

Answer (score 0):

please check this official Android document about Firebase JobDispatcher [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb):

> WorkManager is a library for scheduling and executing deferrable
>   background work in Android. It is the recommended replacement for
>   Firebase JobDispatcher. The following guide will walk you through the
>   process of migrating your Firebase JobDispatcher implementation to
>   WorkManager.